# How to find and remove strings in nsdata

Tags: swift, nsdata, vcf-vcard, cncontact

I'm working on converting vcard to cncontact.

I'm using `CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with data: Data)`.

However, when I tried to import 4000 contacts using that method, I was only able to import 450.

The debug console displays:

```
Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding.
```

A warning appears saying:

```
Will stop this compatibility mapping behavior in the near future.
```

Perhaps there are incorrect characters in the string saved in the contacts. So I want to remove the contacts that are causing the error.

Is it possible to remove incorrect encoding from data converted to NSData format?

I don't know if I can remove the incorrect encoding using the `drop(while:)` function after changing `NSData` to `Data`.

Comment: Can you transform that Data into a `String` according to some String.encoding? If yes, the vCard format is known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard you might search in each contact which line seems strange, and then remove the unwanted characters. And then, find a way to fix them in `Data` parts. But if in the protocol, there should never be a `0x00`, you can filter data and remove them.

Comment: thank you. I was able to solve the problem with your idea. The problem was solved by looking into each Vcard component and deleting the problematic elements.
Thank you again.